# подключение python к Sybase SQL Anywhere

Tags: python

Спасибо за ваш труд, есть эти данные

```
Логин: user
пароль: pass
Database type: Sybase SQL Anywhere
IP адрес: 1.1.1.1
Порт:2222
```

Нужно подключиться к бд через питон.

Пробовал подключиться через sqlanydb

```
import sqlanydb
conn = sqlanydb.connect(uid='dba', pwd='sql', eng='demo', dbn='demo' )
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select 'Hello, world!'")
print( "SQL Anywhere says: %s" % curs.fetchone() )
curs.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Что-нибудь пробовали делать? Приведите ваши попытки и возникшие проблемы

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3319788/13970074

Comment: @dIm0n у вас получилось скачать библиотеку? У меня выдает ошибку: ERROR: unknown command "sybase"

Comment: Я не пробовал качать

Comment: @dIm0n странно даже в пипе его нету.

Comment: http://python-sybase.sourceforge.net/download.html